# What happened to Yuki and Inaho's parents?

Tags: aldnoah-zero

Yuki and Inaho are orphans by the time Aldnoah.Zero opens. Do we know what happened to their parents? Or are we just to assume they died in the mess surrounding Heaven's Fall?

Some have speculated that Saazbaum could somehow have been Inaho's father (given that Saazbaum and Orlane descended to Earth right around the time of Inaho's birth). Is that plausible?

Answer (score 7):

Volume 3 of the Aldnoah.Zero Blu-rays came with a collection of four short narratives about Inaho and Yuki's life well prior to the events of episode 1.

In the second of them, 「春の遠足」 "A Trip in Spring", we learn that Inaho, Yuki, and their mother had been on a train to somewhere when Heaven's Fall occurred. Their mother was killed immediately, probably because a meteor landed near their location (though the story is mostly told from Yuki's point of view, and she, being five-ish years old at the time, obviously doesn't have the best recollection of events). Somehow or the other, Inaho and Yuki both survive, and she, carrying Inaho, follows the crowd of evacuating people, eventually ending up in an underground shelter afterwards.

Their father, a military man, was deployed at the time; a short while after Heaven's Fall, while Inaho and Yuki are still living in the shelter, Yuki receives a letter from the government indicating that they have been deemed war orphans. The implication being, of course, that their father, too, is dead.

The Saazbaum hypothesis is clearly implausible.

Answer (score 0):

yes, his parents died in the first mars-earth war.
and my best guess is that the authors killed off the parents to make his sister look for "motherly-like" and that they had a good bond, and so when she was in trouble, saving her (which is at episode 1) would be better.

Comment: `yes, his parents died in the first mars-earth war` Citation needed, since the question directly asks for the fate of their parents.